# error in script containing grep

Tags: shell, unix

I am getting GREP invalid option error in the code below :

```
file=$(find . -mtime -4 |ls -lt)
for f in $file
do
 po=$(echo $f|cut -d"_" -f2)
 find . -mtime -4 |ls -lt|grep "$po"|while read fn
   do
         if [ -s $fn ]; then #checks if the file is not empty
           if [ -d tmp ]; then
                rm -r tmp
           fi
           mkdir tmp
           cp -p $fn /tmp/$fn
           break
         fi
   done
done
```

Basically I am trying to sort the list which I am getting from find  then looping through it taking the latest non zero file for a PO.

List of file is

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 loneranger loneranger 37 Jul 21 06:30 belk_po12345_20140721.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 loneranger loneranger 24 Jul 22 06:30 belk_po12345_20140722.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 loneranger loneranger  0 Jul 23 06:30 belk_po12345_20140723.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 loneranger loneranger 11 Jul 24 12:00 belk_po12348_20140723.log
```

PO -  po12345 or po12348 these are...

Comment: The `find . -mtime -4 |ls -lt` is not valid construction.

Comment: @Asfakul,Why you are using this command `file=$(find . -mtime -4 |ls -lt)`

Comment: I am using this for sorting list which I am getting out of find command. 
I have changed it to
find . -mtime -4 |xargs ls -lt

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I am trying to sort the list which I am getting from find
>   then looping through it taking the latest non zero file for a PO.

You might use `find` for all of that except the final `sort`:

```
find . -size '+1c' -type f -printf "%f %T@\n" | sort -k2
```

The `find` part search files (`-type f`) of more than 1 byte long (`-size '+1c'`) and for each one print the file's base name (`%f`) and the modified time as seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT (`%T@`). After that, it is a simple sort on the second field (timestamp).

Of course, you might add all the search criterion you need on `find` but that's the basic idea.

And if you want to loop over the result, do as usual:

```
find . -size '+1c' -type f -printf "%f %T@\n" | 
    sort -k2 |
    while read fname mts; do
       # ...
    done
```